# copy Dynamics CRM on Premise to another instance

Tags: copy, dynamics-crm, clone

I am asking for the actions needed to be taken to clone Dynamics CRM on-premise from the production environment to test environment.

Is it just

- open production SQL server,
- Backup PROD_MSCRM Database
- move the file to the test SQL server.
- restore the backup file to Test_MSCRM DB

Can someone help me if this correct and if there any thing else I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after restore you need to create a new Dynamics CRM instance. You do this using the management tooling. Create the organization and choose to import an existing database.